# How should pets/summons/familiars be handled in Fate?

Tags: fate, fate-core, fate-accelerated, animal-companions, extras

I find that having some other entity that, while part of your character conceptually, is separate from their person, adds a lot to an RPG... Whether it's an Engineer's drone, a Warlock's summon or familiar, or just a squirrel that's tagging along, it's clearly an entity that isn't the character itself.
   In Fate, however, I'm not so sure how to handle that. I've had several models in mind, but I need some guidance here:

> 1) **Pure flavour.** It's only in the agreed-upon narrative, and nowhere else. It doesn't interact with combat.
>
> 2) **An aspect.** It can be invoked and compelled, and obviously an important part of your character. It's also *always true*, naturally.
>
> 3) **A stunt.** It acts as an extension of a character's abilities, or the equivalent of a massive stunt a PC can pull off once per X.
>
> 4) **A set of approaches or skills, on a separate sheet.** Sure, the character can be Flashy or Sneaky, or they can Craft and Notice... but their *pet* can Corrupt(+3) or Chase(+2). It acts instead of the PC, on their turn.
>
> 5) **A full character** with stress, skills/approaches, and consequences. The question here is this: should it act instead of the PC's turn, or in addition to it. It would be unpleasant for there to be up to twice as many acting entities as PCs, right?
>
> 6) **A non-combat entity** with maybe a couple of aspects (or not) and no skills, that can't act in combat, but can be commanded by the PC to scout ahead, send messages (*carrier pigeons?*) and perform minor feats using the PC's skillset.

It doesn't have to be one of these, naturally. I just provided some half-answer of my own, I'm looking for a model more than I'm looking for a poll on my own ideas.

Comment: Even without an expert knowledge of Fate I can see this question has issues. You do not define what you mean by appropriate here, which is really important. It would help to have more context about the specific situation you are using familiars in, as it will impact significantly on which solution might be best. Do you have a particular setting? Are all characters having familiars, or is it unique to one of them? etc etc. Basically, what are you trying to actually achieve by introducing familiars into your game?

Comment: This runs up against the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), and is also asking for a unified mechanic to abstract un-like things (eg, tag-along squirrel and combat summon).

Comment: And why would only one be appropriate? Some situations might call for the same entity to be an invokable aspect, while in another it might be more appropriate to apply the Fate fractal and make it a full entity

Comment: Okay, I'm still getting used to the format of the website... specifically, I'm talking about a Warlock's familiar, sent by the large, awful patron he worships to aid him on his quest.

Comment: Bear in mind that question types that work in chat don't necessarily work on the main site.

Comment: Okay, that's a fair point.. should I delete the question or..?

Comment: @Alex Mitan Not necessarily, but you'll need to be a lot more specific if you want it to work. Each of your numbered items could be a different question,  and then we'd probably still need more info on each case.

Comment: Please do not answer in comments.  Help get the question fixed and opened, then post an answer.